# Testing destroy method failure in Controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller which destroys an item in my db.   Currently it looks like this:

```
before_filter(:except => :toggle_item_owned_state) do
    @collection = current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id])
end

def destroy
    @item = @collection.items.find_by_id(params[:id])

    if @item.destroy
        redirect_to collection_items_path(@collection)
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "There was a problem deleting this item."
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Now, I've written a few rspec controller tests to verify the happy path, but I'd like like to test the failure path (ie when @item.destroy fails).   I would imagine the correct way to do this is using some kind of mocking or stubbing, but I can't come up with something that works.

I've tried the following with some variations, but it's not working:

```
        context "delete fails" do
            before(:each) do
                allow(@item).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
                delete :destroy, :collection_id => batman_collection.id, :id => item_in_collection.id
            end

            it "will generate a flash error message" do
                expect(flash[:alert]).to eq("There was a problem saving your collection.")
            end
        end
```

If anyone out there can provide me some direction or sample code on how to do this, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why would the destroy fail? What validations do you have in your model for this?

Comment: Fair question.  There are no validations in place, however, I can see non-validation related reasons for failure.   Perhaps a db hiccup.   Are you basically saying I should take out the condition and just assume the destroy will work?

Comment: I would still like to understand why I am unable to stub out the destroy call and simulate a failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you setting `@item` in the spec? I suspect it's not actually being stubbed.

Update:

Without seeing your controller, I can't give the exact code, but normally it would be something like this:

```
item = double
allow(Item).to receive(:find).and_return(item)
allow(item).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
```

Update 2:

Expanding out, you set `item` with:

```
current_user.collections.find(params[:collection_id]).items.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

This is a very long chain of calls. RSpec has ways of dealing this, but they are in a section called [Working with legacy code](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/working-with-legacy-code) which says **Usage of these features
should be considered a code smell**.

One approach to improve the code could be to introduce a [service object](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html):

```
class FindItem
  def self.call(item_id, collection_id, user)
    user.collections.find(params[:collection_id]).items.find_by_id(item)
  end
end
```

This is much simpler to stub, and helps to decouple the controller from the DB structure. `destroy` can now be stubbed with:

```
item = double
allow(FindItem).to receive(:call).and_return(item)
allow(item).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
```

Comment: I guess that's the problem.  Where would it be set?   Do I need to do something like: allow(assigns[:item]).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false) because I tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: The controller code is posted above.  Is there anything else you'd like to see.   I tried the above and it didn't work either.   I'm new to stubbing and mocking so your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Show how `@collection` is set.

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know, but there is very useful information here.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.   The general concept worked.   I didn't create a service object, but skinnied out the controller by putting the logic to find the item in the model and then stubbed it out similarly to what you proposed.